# Combining sum of floor functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider a simple sum of floor functions:
$$S = c\left\lfloor \frac{x}{a}\right\rfloor + d\left\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor$$

Can we combine these two terms into a single function?  I am trying to simplify something like this to avoid successive divisions in a computer program.

My question, in general, is: can we combine the following $k$ terms to avoid performing $k$ divisions and multiplications of $x$:
$$S(x,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}c_i\left\lfloor \frac{x}{a_i}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Are you assuming anything about $a,b,c,d$ (e.g. that they are positive integers)?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that every coefficient is a positive integer

Comment: No such combination formula in general. Computation-wise (assuming $x$ is a variable and $a_i$ are constants) you could save the divisions by pre-computing $1/a_i$ to reduce it to multiplications in the loop.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that no such combination formula exists?  I.e., can we prove that the summation given above **must** require _k_ operations to find S(x,k) for a given _x_?

Comment: Are you trying to build the table of $S(x, k)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

A simple compute, **this might not be a proof** :

Assume $\exists a, b \in \Bbb N $ s.t. $\forall x$

$$\left[\frac{x}{2}\right] + \left[\frac{x}{3}\right] = a\left[\frac{x}{b}\right]$$

put x = 2 :

$$a\left[\frac{2}{b}\right] = 1$$

$$\Rightarrow a = 1, b = 2$$

But $\left[\frac{x}{2}\right] + \left[\frac{x}{3}\right] > \left[\frac{x}{2}\right]$ for large enough $x$.

This form might not be able to simplify **if the denominators has no limitation**.

Comment: Did you mean to conclude $b=2$?

Comment: Oh thanks @Matthew Conroy

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you attempting to prove that such an _a,b_ exist or are you showing that they do not exist?

Comment: @Nisrak, a, b do not exist.

Comment: I see. Any ideas to develop a more complete proof?  Maybe we can somehow equate this to combining terms of a polynomial, which you obviously can't do?

Comment: err ... if they can combining to a polynomial, then the polynomial should be linear.